# When to include the <string> header in your program?

Tags: c++, syntax

Do you include the "string" header when a library such as "iostream" already provides a solution?

**Example: Do you include the string library if you have already included the iostream library? Which is the right professional method?**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;
int main() {
    ifstream fin;
    fin.open("input.txt");
    string data;
    fin >> data;
    cout << data << endl; // Works with <iostream>, and without <string>
    fin.close();
    return 0;
}
```

**Example 2: Use string library if another library provides functionality, even if program compiles without string?**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;
int main() {
    ifstream fin;
    fin.open("input.txt");
    string data;
    fin >> data;       
    cout << data << endl; // Even though <iostream> allowed program to compile, we include the <string> library.
    fin.close();
    return 0;
}
```

Received points off my CSC 101 class programming assignment because even though program worked, teacher said when using the string datatype I needed to include the string library. Even though technically it was fine without it possibly. *Thats the question.*

Comment: I edited it because of your statement.

Comment: If you're using anything from the standard library, you should `#include` the appropriate header file.  Your issue extends way beyond `<string>`.

Comment: Thank you, it is CSC 101 so I wanted to make sure. It did not make since to include extra libraries when your program already compiles.

Comment: One thing you'll have to get used to with C++, and this is C++'s fault, is that "it compiles" does not mean "it is right" and therefore does not mean "it will always compile" (or even "it will always work properly despite compiling")

Comment: @Raymond Go to a site like [this one](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector).  See near the top where the header file is specified.  Even though the example is `vector`, you should always make sure you are including the correct header file.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your teacher was correct.

Your program worked without `<string>` *by chance*. Your standard library implementation, of that version, on that platform, under those circumstances, on that day, transitively included what you needed via `<iostream>`. The standard library is just code, like yours, and it just so happens that your particular implementation contains, inside `<iostream>`, an `#include <string>`. It could be buried behind many other `#include`s but got there eventually. But that's honestly pure chance, and does not mean that this is something the language guarantees, or something that must always be the case even in practice.

You should always code to standards.

**If you're using [features from `<string>`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/string), include `<string>`.**

Just today I was trying to build my big project with a new toolchain and found a few places where I'd accidentally relied on transitive includes, and it broke the build as a result because the new standard library implementation had a slightly different arrangement of headers. I dutifully added the missing `#include`s and now the world is a better place for it.

Comment: The shown program doesn't use anything from `<string>` though.

Comment: @eerorika You're right, but the first revision of the question hinted at a non-broken MCVE that probably inserted a `std::string` to `std::cout`, and frankly I'm just brazenly ignoring all of that for the sake of directly answering the question from the prose because it's late and I cba. But yes you are right.

Comment: Now in the third revision (OP is all over the place) he's talking about "the string datatype" so yeah I'm just throwing this out there and letting the OP decide whether it sticks, quite honestly :)

Comment: Thank you, I will take your word on this. I edited my post a little more to give you a better idea of what the program was for. We were reading in a string from a file, and outputting it to a new file.

Comment: @Raymond You're welcome. Next time please show a proper reproducing example up-front rather than taking us on a journey of discovery through four different versions of the question in 15 minutes

Comment: @LightNessRacesinOrbit I will, sorry. Had to wait 10 minutes to accept right answer.